# Can I change the behavior of the Home and End keys on an Apple Keyboard with Numeric Keypad?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I just bought an "Apple Keyboard with Numeric Keypad", then I connected it to my Macbook Pro running Lion.

But the `home` and `end` key under the `F14` key doesn't work as I expected. Say in "Pages", the `home` key doesn't bring the cursor to the beginning of the line, while the `end` key takes you to the bottom of the page.

Does anyone know how to re-map the `home`/`end` key?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

One option is to create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
  "\UF729"  = moveToBeginningOfLine:;
  "\UF72B"  = moveToEndOfLine:;
  "$\UF729" = moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:;
  "$\UF72B" = moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:;
}
```

Quit and reopen applications to apply the changes. Note that `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` is not supported by some applications like Xcode or Firefox.

In Terminal you can assign home (↖) to control-a and end (↘) to control-e from Preferences > Settings > Keyboard. That will leave you with no key combinations to scroll to the top or bottom of a window though.

It might be easier to just use the default keybindings. In most native text views:

- control-A or option-up goes to the beginning of a paragraph
- control-E or option-down goes to the end of a paragraph
- command-left goes to the beginning of a line
- command-right goes to the end of a line

Comment: This works on most of my apps like Pages and Textmate. But, I couldn't get it working in Terminal

Comment: Right. Terminal is another story, and you'll need to tell it how you want the Home and End keys to behave. You can do that in Terminal -> Preferences -> Keyboard. Set the Home key to send `control-a` and End key to send `control-e`. Those are the Emacs-style keybindings that the Terminal uses for line movement by default. It'll mimic the regular home/end movement you're after.

Comment: Thanks again Michael. I'll try it out tonight when I get back to my laptop.

Comment: Works in macOS Sierra! (Karabiner is not working at the moment).

Comment: @ckpepper02 RIGHT? I mean so frustrating and pointless 99% of the time since PgUp and PgDown get you to the same point for all but the longest of docs. Grrr!

Comment: zomg thank you, have googld this so many timez...and yes it is pointless in Terminal. Here, here's the beginning of your terminal session from 2 wks. ago... did they QA that, ever?

Answer (score 32):

Another option is to enable the "Use PC Style Home/End" setting in [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) (formerly KeyRemap4MacBook):

[image]

The setting is defined in [Resources/include/checkbox/for_pc_users.xml](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/for_pc_users.xml).

You can also save a file like this as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>HOMEENDIGNORE</appname>
    <equal>com.microsoft.Word</equal>
    <equal>com.microsoft.Powerpoint</equal>
    <equal>com.microsoft.Excel</equal>
    <equal>com.vmware.fusion</equal>
    <prefix>com.vmware.proxyApp.</prefix>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>homeend</name>
    <identifier>homeend</identifier>
    <not>HOMEENDIGNORE</not>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::HOME, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::A, VK_CONTROL</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::END, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::E, VK_CONTROL</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::HOME, VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::A, VK_CONTROL | VK_SHIFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::END, VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::E, VK_CONTROL | VK_SHIFT</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then open the KeyRemap4MacBook application, press the ReloadXML button, and enable the setting. See https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en for more information.

Answer (score 14):

Since this answer ranks well in search engines, I want to explain how I did it with the latest version of [Karabiner](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements).
The "Use PC Style Home / End" setting has to be downloaded from their website. You will want to go to "Complex Modifications", then "Add Rule" and then choose "Import more rules from the Internet". It will take you to this website: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/ where under "Emulation Modes" you can find "PC-Style Shortcuts". Once you click "Import into Karabiner-Elements", you can just activate it and are ready to go 
You will only need to choose "Add rule" and find the "Use PC Style Home / End" setting right there.

[image: complex-modifications page]

Comment: You are my hero.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you the awesome [keyremap4macbook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/), it's free amd despite the name it works on any mac (not necessarily macbooks) and [here](http://architectryan.com/2012/10/03/remap-home-and-end-on-os-x-mountain-lion/) you can find the easiest way to change the default behaviour of home/end buttons to work like they should (IMO)

Comment: I concur, I more frequently `home` and `end` on a line basis rather than on a full document basis. Got to do everything we can to reduce the friction to executing the most frequent use cases and push keyboard shortcut combinations and the like to less frequent commands.

Answer (score -1):

I followed [this blog post](http://heisencoder.net/2008/04/fixing-up-mac-key-bindings-for-windows.html) and it did the "home" and "end" key bindings as well as a few other userful adjustments.

Comment: We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions