# Mapping Home and End of Apple keyboard in VMWare fusion

Tags: keyboard, vmware

I have mapped the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys of my apple keyboard to work PC style: Go to the beginning of the line and end respectively. (Using [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) if that is important, I am aware of [other ways](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18016/can-i-change-the-behavior-of-the-home-and-end-keys-on-an-apple-keyboard-with-nume) of doing this, and open to alternatives if that would solve my problem)

I use Windows 7 using VMware fusion (primarily for C# development on Visual Studio). When I have this set up (<kbd>Home</kbd> = Beginning of line...), I am unable to use this on Windows, when I have not set this up, it works "as expected" on Widows (to beginning of line) but on the Mac, I have the default mac behavior.

I tried remapping the keys using Vmware preferences, but the <kbd>Home</kbd> key is recognized as "Left" for some reason:

*This is what happens when I press the Home key:*
[image: This is what happens when I press the Home key]

Currently I change this setting every time I switch between windows running Windows apps and those running mac apps, but I am finding it more and more frustrating.

Is there a way to somehow have both? Meaning some kind of setting that makes <kbd>Home</kbd> to go to the beginning of the line on both Windows and Mac apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[KeyMap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) can actually do this. As I told in the question, the problem is Windows and Mac OSX interpret <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> differently. So what I needed was an app that allowed me to have different mappings for different apps (Windows is in VM Ware or Parallels, which are apps)

KeyMap4MacBook allows to have different key mappings for the Mac and different ones for VMs / Remote Desktops:
[image: KeyMap4MacBook allows you to configure Home and End keys for all apps except VMs and Remote desktop Connection]

Comment: I'm looking at the next version, Karabiner-Elements but I can't seem to make the Home and End modifications work only on Mac but not when in Virtual machines....